# Проблема при запуске JavaFX приложения

Tags: java, javafx

При запуске приложения, которое использует JavaFX получаю ошибку:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class
> ru.test.mis.JavaFxSpringIntegrator (in unnamed module @0x3fc2959f)
> cannot access class com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl (in module
> javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export
> com.sun.javafx.application to unnamed module @0x3fc2959f

Саму библиотеку добавил, в конфигурации в VM options добавил строку:

```
--module-path
"C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-19\lib"
--add-modules=javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.fxml
```

Не помогает. Что еще необходимо сделать? Использую JDK 11

Answer (score 0):

После `--add-modules` уберите =, просто поставьте пробел: `--module-path "C:\javafx-sdk-19\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml` как тут, и не забудьте добавить javafx к библиотекам проекта: `File -> Project Structure -> Libraries -> New -> Java -> путь к библиотеке JavaFx`